# VBA, how to make formulas visible in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, range, formula, cells

```
Dim n As Double
n = Sh.Range("B10").Value

Dim rate As Double
rate = (datefin - datedepart) / n

Cells(13, n + 3) = datefin

For y = n - 1 To x Step -1
Cells(13, y + 3) = datefin - rate
datefin = datefin - rate
Next y
```

I have this simple `for` loop, that puts the values into the cells in excel starting from `n` (given by the user) and going backwards according to a `rate` (which is also calculated by values given by the user).

The output values I get are correct, but I would like to make my formulas visible in excel. For example, if I press on the cell `D13` I would like it to show the formula I used. I tried to do it with the `ActiveCell.Formula` or `ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1` function but since `n` is not always a specific number (and hence on a specific cell) I cannot find how to execute what I want.

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 2):

In general you would use `.Formula` to attach a formula to a cell, however if the individual components aren't actually contained in other cells of your spreadsheet the best you are going to be able to do is something like

```
Cells(13, y + 3).Formula = "=" & format(datefin) & " - " & format(rate)
```

Which if datefin is 9 and rate is 2 would put the formula `"=9 - 2"` in the cell.